# How to keep ball moving

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a simple app with a ball moving around reflecting off the screen edges.
I've found out how to create my ball. However i'm not able to move it around.

Here's my code till now.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    initial_x=100;
    initial_y=100;
    speed_x=1;
    speed_y=1;
    x=initial_x;
    y=initial_y;

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
    draw();

}
private void draw() {



    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;



    Log.d("dimensions",String.valueOf(width));
    Log.d("dimensions",String.valueOf(height));


    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.RGB_565);

    g = new Canvas(bitmap);
    g.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.drawCircle(50,50, 20, paint); //Put your values

    // In order to display this image, we need to create a new ImageView that we can display.
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);

    // Set this ImageView's bitmap to ours
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    // Create a simple layout and add imageview to it.
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

    layout.addView(imageView, params);
    layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

    // Show layout in activity.
    setContentView(layout);

    layout.setOnClickListener(l);



}
```

I've set an onclick listener to basically be able to move the ball when i touch the screen. How do I make this a continuous process?

Edit:

I changed the onclicklistener to an ontouchlistener to keep the ball moving while i touch the screen but it still works like an onclick listener. here is the code

```
OnTouchListener l = new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {


        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch(event.getAction())
        {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            g.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
            x+=speed_x;
            y+=speed_y;
            g.drawCircle(x, y, 20, paint);
            if(x==0)
                speed_x=-1;
            if(x==height)
                speed_x=1;
            if(y==0)
                speed_y=-1;
            if(y==width)
                speed_y=1;
            v.invalidate();
            break;

        }

        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Write the invalidate() method to the last line of the draw() method

Comment: Do you mean add v.invalidate() to the last line of draw()?

Comment: Yes but its only invalidate() because is an method of your class where the draw() method is

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`TimerTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) to periodically update the position continuously. Probably 10 to 30 times a second should suffice.

Put your drawing and position update logic in the `run()` method of `TimerTask` since creating another thread won't work. (Drawing must occur on GUI thread).

Hope this helps.

**Edit:**

```
TimerTask myTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Update logic here

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Drawing logic here
            }
        });
    }
}
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(myTimerTask, 50, 50);
```

Comment: Can you show the members of the class you are using to store position of ball?

Comment: as of now im only using two integers to store their coordinates.